# GStreamer command line to concatenate two .avi videos

Tags: linux, gstreamer, gst-launch

Could someone give me an example gst-launch-0.10 command line pipe, which concatenates two videos together and outputs a single .avi video file.

I've seen a few examples which use gnlcomposition and smpte, however being honest I don't know too much about those plugins, so would like to steer clear if possible.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything so far? please show some effort :) maybe you are not used to StackOverflow yet.. you have to provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - that is something that you have but maybe is not working etc..

Comment: Not a problem. I have successfully created videos using gstreamer before, on command line and through the C API. I could post an example pipeline if that helps. I haven't tried putting together a concatenation pipeline as of yet. I was hoping to work from an example pipeline, or even an explanation of what should go into the pipeline.

Comment: well you can use filesrc, [concat](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-concat.html)  - but I am not sure if it was available at time of 0.10 .. you may check [this](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Best-way-to-concatenate-and-play-streams-td4659182.html)

Comment: As you say, concat does't look like it's available for 0.10, which probably explains why I can't find many example pipelines, without incorporating gnlcomposition and smpte.  When you say use filesrc, do you mean, I can have a single pipeline with two filesrc inputs? I wasn't aware gstreamer had this capability...

Comment: yes you can have one pipeline with two filesrc.. when using gst-launch you just do not put ! but add space ' ' .. like `filesrc ! processing ! mux name=m filesrc ! processing ! m.` another [example](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-videomixer.html) .. I hope this was working in 0.10 but I guess yes

Comment: Interesting. I will give it a go. Just on a separate subject, could I have pipeline which has a number of filesrc's, which are images, and produce a single video, like a time-lapse video for example?  I've done something like this before using multifilesrc, but it's not exactly perfect at the moment. Thanks

Comment: but that will not solve your problem! its just that you can have two filesrc in one pipeline, it will not concat them - sorry for misunderstanding - [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-concat.html)  you see what I meant - but you still need something that will join the two together